# What is the difference between defdelegate and def with call module function directly in Elixir

Tags: function, module, elixir

I have module that is mostly used as a namespace. Let us call it `Bla`. There are other submodules, that have methods with specific functions to that submodule.

However, I want to have two options:

1. import main module `Bla` and use all functions from submodules directly (not to write multiple imports separately)
2. import only specific submodule like `Bla.Subbla` to use functions only from this module without importing functions from other submodules

This is what I have:

```elixir
defmodule Bla do
  defdelegate bla_func(text), to: Bla.Subbla
  defdelegate bla_func(text, opts), to: Bla.Subbla
end
    
defmodule Bla do
  def bla_func(text), do: Bla.Subbla.bla_func(text)
  def bla_func(text, opts), do: Bla.Subbla.bla_func(text, opts)
end
```

What is the right way to do that? I have two options, but have no idea, maybe, there is much more better one. Are those two options equivalent? And which one is preferable? Is there any difference in performance?

Comment: I think you should consider using `use` and pass options to it regarding what you want to import.

Comment: sounds nice, will read about this option (i'm just learning - know not that much at the moment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few differences I can think of:

1. When you are using `defdelegate` your intent is very clear, you are just delegating the method to another method in another module. And that this is just a dumb forwarder.
2. With `defdelegate` you cannot change the `arguments`, whether be it the order, addition or removal of arguments. So, if all you really want is to forward the method call use `defdelgate` as there is less scope to screw up.
3. In some cases `defdelegate` is not an option as you need to add more data to the forwarding function, in which case you don't really have an option.

So, the bottomline is: if possible always use `defdelegate`, you will avoid a few classes of bugs using it. e.g. below:

```elixir
defmodule Greet do
  def greet(name, greeting) do
    IO.puts "#{greeting} #{name}"
  end
end
    
defmodule DelegatedGreet do
  defdelegate greet(name, greeting), to: Greet
end
    
defmodule BuggyGreet do
  # scope for bugs like these
  def greet(name, greeting), do: Greet.greet(greeting, name)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As @JustMichael told, it's good to use `use` in this case. It does exactly what I need.

```
defmodule SomeModuleWhereINeedSubbla do
  use Bla

  useful_func   # => Will print "Bla.Subbla.useful_func"
end

defmodule Bla do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import Bla.Subbla
    end
  end
end

defmobule Bla.Subbla do
  def useful_func(), do: IO.puts "Bla.Subbla.useful_func"
end
```

Comment: This answer is accepted as an alternative, but it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: yeap, really, that is not an answer. would be nice to hear if you know the answer :)

Comment: this is not a good enough reason to use a Macro, macros have a very wide and far reaching scope, better code tries to scope down stuff as much as possible.